# Why am I unable to access Object Explorer in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: windows-10, ms-sql, visual-studio-2019

For reference, I am using MS-SSMS version 14.0.17289.0 and I have Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 installed, on Windows 10.

I am unable to locate or open Object Explorer. I have installed the Microsoft SQL Express server to go through the database tutorial, however, when I go to the View dropdown menu there is no option for Object Explorer. 
I have tried going into View > Registered Servers and right-clicking on the server then clicking object explorer, but this does absolutely nothing. I have checked this by opening the Telemetry log, which records entries for opening the server menu but does not change when I click the object explorer option.

Why is Object Explorer not in the View menu, and why does clicking it from the server menu do nothing? How do I open it?

Comment: What version of SQL Express did you install exactly?

Comment: I installed SQL Server 2017 Express edition.

Comment: In order to eliminate a possible incompatible problem upgrade to [SSMS 18.2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: That fixed it, I uninstalled and reinstalled as 18.2. 
I'm not entirely familiar with stack exchange, should I submit this as an answer to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For reference I am using MS-SSMS version 14.0.17289.0 and I have Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 installed, on Windows 10.  For reference, I am using MS-SSMS version 14.0.17289.0 and I have Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 installed, on Windows 10.  I am unable to locate or open Object Explorer. I have installed the SQL Server 2017 Express.

You are using an incompatible version of Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio which does not support SQL Server 2017 Express.  The simplest solution is to install the current version of [Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-2017).

> Why is Object Explorer not in the View menu, and why does clicking it from the server menu do nothing? How do I open it?

It likely has to do with the fact you are running an incompatible version of SSMS.